[Couchbase Capella]: Curl timeout when using couchbases schema
When running a curl command to a local couchbase server for rebalance endpoint, it works (given username and password are both couchbase).
curl  -u couchbase:couchbase -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/rebalanceProgress

When I uses couchbase capella url (svc-***.cloud.couchbase.com), It does not work. What am I missing ?

can you be more specific about what "does not work" means? Also, make sure to check the Capella REST API reference: https://docs.couchbase.com/cloud/management-api-reference/index.html

https://www.couchbase.com/forums/t/couchbase-capella-curl-timeout-when-using-couchbases-schema/38382
